# Code-First, when I go enable-migrations, I get “No context type was found in the assembly 'DOC'”

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Code-First, create a website using the standard template and then kept adding tables to the main `applicationDBContext`, however now when I go **Enable-Migrations** in **Package Manager** Console I get

> No context type was found in the assembly 'DOC'.

and when I put the full path using:

```
ContextTypeName Option enable-migrations -ContextTypeName DOC.Migrations.Configuration
```

...I get:

> Migrations have already been enabled in project 'DOC'. To overwrite the existing migrations configuration, use the -Force parameter.

And when I go **-Force**, it says

> Code First Migrations enabled for project DOC.

but when I try to **add-migration** I get

> Error CS0311 The type 'DOC.Migrations.Configuration' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'DbMigrationsConfiguration'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DOC.Migrations.Configuration' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'. DOC xxxxxxx\DOC\Migrations\Configuration.cs.

When I check the **Configuration.cs** file it changed it from:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration
```

...to:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration
```

...causing the project fails to build

The only time that I managed get this working by downgrading the entityframework from 6.1.3 to **6.1.2** and then re-upgrade.

Sometimes, I have to upgrade and downgrade couple of times, close VS and re-open and then it works.

Is there a solution to this? its very annoying.

[image]

I have also noticed that my `DbContext` class derives from `IdentityDBContext`, is this ok? I know usually you derive it from `DbContext`, but since I started the project using the wizard, it created this automatically and I just added my other tables to it.

[image]

My web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --><!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --><!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --><!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --><!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --><!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --><!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --><!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --><!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --><!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=localhost\SQLTEST;initial catalog=DOC;User Id=xxx;Password=xxxx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=zzzzz;initial catalog=DOC;User Id=zzzzzz;Password=zzzzz;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework.MappingAPI" publicKeyToken="7ee2e825d201459e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.1.0.9" newVersion="6.1.0.9" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing the parameters for `enable-migrations` and `add-migration`.

`enable-migrations` has a context type name. You are specifying the configuration name, not the context.

```
enable-migrations -ContextTypeName DOC.Models.ApplicationDbContext
```

Then to add:

```
add-migration MyMigrationName -ConfigurationTypeName DOC.Migrations.Configuration
```

I'm not sure you even need the parameters since it looks like you have a single project. Here is the [command reference](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/)

It does not matter that you are inheriting from IdentityDbContext. Also, EF doesn't have version 6.3 and 6.4, it is 6.1.3 or EF Core.

Comment: It again doesn't work, so when I put the suggested line, I get <br/> Migrations have already been enabled in project 'DOC'. To overwrite the existing migrations configuration, use the -Force parameter. <br/> and when I go with -Force parameter, i get <br/> The type 'DOC.Migrations.Configuration' does not inherit from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. Migrations configuration types must extend from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration' <br/><br/>  and with regards to EF, Sorry I meant 6.1.3

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you already have migrations enabled. You can [reset them](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jan/13/Resetting-Entity-Framework-Migrations-to-a-clean-Slate) if needed. Everything is in one project, correct? You shouldn't need any parameters. `enable-migrations` -> `add-migration myNewMigration` -> `update-database`.

Comment: yep, all in one project, trying add-migration test, I get "No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'DOC'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration)."

Comment: Do you have the correct project selected in the console? If you've done a lot of downgrading and upgrading you may want to remove EF, make sure the web.config is clean, clean your solution, delete your .suo file and then add EF back, etc.

Comment: IF I remove it and re-install, I have to uninstall other related packages, I just did update-package -reinstall EntityFramework and then I downgraded to 6.1.2 and it works now, the thing is, it will break again after I shutdown VS and have to fiddle again with it,  I actually just done this and its showing the same stupid message (no migration configuration type was found......etc)

Comment: You may have some garbage in your web.config. Should be no reason you can't use EF 6.1.3 which has been out there a while. Post the entity framework portions of your web.config.

Comment: this is my web.config

Answer (score 3):

In case you have multiple projects inside your solution and you are using ***Code First*** approach then did you check whether you have selected the correct "*default project*" in **package manager console.**?

please refer the image below

Try it.

[image]

Comment: small thing but sometime it takes a lot of time to find out that. Package Manager console's default project was wrong on my case! Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new project, just to check what we need. Ok so you go file> new> project, under visual c# menu new asp.net web application, choose any name for the project, this is just to check what it missing in your project. You click ok, select MVC in the left side, and in the right side is the step missing. You can see a change authentication button, and under that button says, authentication: No authentication, click there and select individual user accounts. Click ok and that option, automatically install entity and identity. That is the problem. Hope i can help, feel free to contact me again.

Answer (score 0):

In Case you are using **EntityFrameworkCore** with multiple DBContext's this solved it for me:

In PackageManager:

```
PM>EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration AName -Context my.namespace.ADbContext
```